# $* \ ||, eval and "\; mean?

Tags: shell, scripting

Could you please explain the below code? What does `$*` `\` `||`, `eval` and `"\;` mean?

Here below are the functions

```
Initialization_variables 
error_message
quit_error_chk 

Initialization_variables $* \
|| eval error_message "Error in Initialization_variables function ..."\
; quit_error_chk 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments the symbols can mostly be found by looking in `man sh` and searching for those characters.  Here's a summary:

`$*` expands to the command line parameters passed to the script

`\` escapes the next character from interpretation by the shell, in these cases, it continues the current command line to the next line.

`||` is the shell "or" operator.  The command after the `||` will be executed only if the command before the `||` failed.

`eval` Concatenate all the arguments with spaces.  Then re-parse and execute the command.  It appears to have no reason to be in this script.

`"\`  Actually not related to each other. The quote terminates the preceding literal string, the backslash continues the command to the next line.

Please consult `man sh` for more details and proper usage of these features.